# Как определить, монета с комиссией или без используя sdk uniswap.org

Tags: javascript, typescript, ethereum, solidity

Я пытаюсь создать и отправить транзакцию на https://app.uniswap.org с помощью SDK: https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/

uniswap выполняет две функции:

- swapExactTokensForETH  - токены без комиссии
- swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens) токены с комиссией

Как определить, монета с комиссией или без?  Не отправляя транзакцию

В противном случае, если отправлено неправильно, транзакция не состоится.

Comment: вот это отвечает на твой вопрос? https://uniswap.org/faq/#how-can-i-see-my-liquidity-provider-fees

Comment: к сожалению это не совсем то, там можно посмотреть комиссию самого пула ликвидности,  а нужно именно FEE у токена, который обрабатывается с функцией swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens